# HTML Slider with jquery display first slide for too long

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Background:**
Script below is used for HTML slider. Jquery is written to rotate slides every 10 seconds. When the page is opened or refreshed, the 1st ad display for 20 seconds.

Any idea why?

Here is my script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Current Ads Display</title>


<style>
object {
/* Set rules to fill background */
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
}
</style>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script>
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(0)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  10000);
```

```
<body>
<?PHP
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
//Getting ads from the database
require_once('connect_pdo.php');
$sqlst = $conn->prepare("SELECT `adslist` FROM ADS");
$sqlst->execute();
while($resultst = $sqlst -> fetch()){
$adlist = $resultst["adslist"];
echo "<div class='slideshow'>";
//Display ad as an image
//<object data='/$adlist'></object>
echo "<object data='/$adlist'></object>";
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It'll be great if you can provide a pure html sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove hide option outside and give that in inside the interval it will work.

```
<script>
setInterval(function() { 

$('#slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

},  10000);
```